# Bind a value in dropdown in ngFor when json property is undefinded

Tags: angular, ngfor

In my angular application, I have a dropdown inside an `ngFor`. The value of the dropdown will be set as per the value in the `ngFor` iteration. The value of the dropdown will be set as per the value in `ElementsList` array.
The `ElementsList` array looks like `var ElementsList = [{id:1, name:"Sample Name", active:true}]`

```
            <div *ngFor="let element of ElementsList">
                <select [(ngModel)]="element.active" >
                  <option value="" >--Select--</option>
                  <option value="true" >Enable</option>
                  <option value="false" >Disable</option>    
                </select>
           </div>
```

Now, sometimes the response will not contain active property in the array. which means the ElementsList array looks like

```
var ElementsList = [{id:1, name:"Sample Name"}]
```

In this case, no value is getting selected in the dropdown. My requirement is to set the drop down to false, if in case the active property is missing.

Is it possible to handle it in template itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use boolean values instead of strings passed in the option values (so to use bindings in `[]` signs):

```html
<div *ngFor="let element of ElementsList">
  <select [(ngModel)]="element.active">
    <option [value]=""> --Select-- </option>
    <option [value]="true"> Enable </option>
    <option [value]="false"> Disable </option>    
  </select>
</div>
```

then you can split the `ngModel` declaration from two-way into two one-way syntaxes.
To assign value you can use `??` operator to fall back to false, when not specified. To update the value use function in the component.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let element of elementsList">
  <select [ngModel]="element.active ?? false" (ngModelChange)="update(element, $event)">
    <option [value]="undefined">--Select--</option>
    <option [value]="true">Active</option>
    <option [value]="false">Inactive</option>
  </select>
</ng-container>
```

```js
export class AppComponent {
  elementsList = [
    {
      id: '2396',
      name: 'Sample 1',
      active: true,
    },
    {
      id: '434',
      name: 'Sample 2',
    },
  ];

  update(element, value) {
    element.active = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But that throws parse error for me. "error NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 21 in [element.active ?? false=$event]"

Comment: well, there should be no "=$event" right?

Comment: That was added in the error. I have created a Stackblitz for this. Can you pls try your code here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsw9n7-b75rrp

Comment: ah, right - that's because you are using two-way ngModel binding - therefore we can't use the nullish operator here...

I will make some changes in my post :)

Comment: In this case, "Select" will be selected for undefined cases. My requirement is to make false selected.

Comment: okay, then you need to implement ngModel separately, will update my answer :)